# Printing a line at the bottom of the console/terminal

Tags: python, terminal, stdout

Using Python, I would like to print a line that will appear on the last *visible* line on the console the script is being ran from. For example, something like this:

[image]

Would this be able to be done?

Comment: From the screenshot this looks like a Windows terminal question; should it work on Unix terminals as well?

Comment: It would be better if it could. Although it's not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [effbot.org's `Console` module](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm):

```
import Console

c = Console.getconsole()
c.text(0, -1, 'And this is the string at the bottom of the console')
```

By specifying `-1` for the second (line) argument you are addressing the last line of the console.

Because the `Console` module only works on Windows, to get this to work on UNIX terminals as well, you should take a look at the [`wcurses` library](https://github.com/adamv/wcurses), which provides a partial `curses` implementation that'll work on Windows. You'd drive it the same as the [stdlib `curses` module](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html); use the first on Windows, the latter on UNIX.

Comment: I don't think effbot has a download for their module for Python 2.7, I tried downloading the 2.6 version but it would not let me install.

Comment: He does provide the source code, perhaps you can compile it yourself? I know, Python extensions on Windows are a pain. The wcurses module also requires compilation.

Comment: Can the text written at the bottom of the console edited? // The link seems dead: it says `effbot.org is taking a break. We’ll be back, in some form or another.`

Comment: @alper I’ll try and update the answer soon. In the meantime, know that effbot’s project was Python 2 only. You could take a look at https://pypi.org/project/UniCurses instead.  I’ll probably use that to update this answer with.

Comment: @MartijnPieters seems like https://pypi.org/project/UniCurses/ is abondened .

Comment: @alper: https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses / https://pypi.org/project/Uni-Curses/ appears to have picked up the torch.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have look into `unicurses` but was unable to find related example regarding to print text at the bottom of terminal

Comment: @alper: the [`addstr()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.addstr) lets you position text within a curses window. See the [unicurses `test_windows.py` demo](https://github.com/unicurses/unicurses/blob/master/demos/test_windows.py) for how to get a window and its size; just create one for the maximum column and line count, without a box.

Comment: I was more likely to achieve output like tmux does (like it shows date at right bottom corner) where print a text at the bottom of the console/terminal

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows terminal try the [console module](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) For unix the curses module would do.