# How can I have terminal outputs while also having a progress bar at the bottom of the terminal in Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, stdout, flush

I want to have various terminal printouts while also having a progress bar displayed at the same place on the terminal (say, the bottom) and I want this to work in Python 2 and 3. The code I have now is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time

maximumValue = 10
for i in range(0, maximumValue):
    #print("my count number: {count}".format(count = i))
    sys.stdout.write("\r[" + i * "=" + ">" + (maximumValue - i - 1) * " " + "]")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)

sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

The progress bar prints out reasonably here, but when I include the print statement, the progress bar gets printed such that it appears multiple times in the terminal. How can I get a single progress bar to appear while also printing terminal outputs?

Comment: maybe overkill but you could use the `curses` module; [here](http://blog.skeltonnetworks.com/2010/03/python-curses-custom-progress-bar/) is an example. or this https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/ ?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can try the [`Console`](http://effbot.org/zone/console-index.htm) module, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10774257/1757964), combined with an ASCII progress bar like the one in your question. You mentioned the problem that the progress bar itself appears multiple times on your terminal; the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/1757964) generally cover that. For instance, you could try [aviraldg's progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173331/1757964) with the `Console` module:

```
import Console
c = Console.getconsole()
progress = 50
c.text(0, -1, "\r[{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(progress/10), progress))
```